# Which scripture contains the origin of Nataraja stotram composed by patanjali muni?

Tags: scripture, shiva, stotra, patanjali, story

I got a story from a website regarding Nataraja Stotram.
It goes as follows:

> Once upon a time, as the story of the origin of the hymn goes, Nandi,
> Shiva's carrier would not allow Patanjali Muni to have Darshan of the
> Lord Shiva (Nataraja of Chidambaram). In order to reach Lord Shiva,
> Patanjali, with his mastery over grammatical forms, spontaneously
> composed this prayer in praise of the Lord without using any extended
> (`diirgham') syllable, (without` charaNa' and `shR^{}iN^{}ga' i.e.
> leg and horn) to tease Nandi. Shiva was quickly pleased, gave Darshan
> to the devotee, and danced to the lilting tune of this song. The place
> where this incidence is said to have happened is Chidambaram (also
> known as Thillai), located about a hundred miles from Madras,
> Tamilnadu, India. It is considered to be one of the holiest places in
> India.

I want to know which scripture contains this story?

Link of the site:
https://shaivam.org/scripture/English-Script/147/nataraj-stotra